# ANTLR4 - what is the reason of prioritizing one rule over another in mode in lexer?

Tags: regex, antlr4

Our setup:

parser.g4:

```
absolute_schema_nodeid : (SLASH identifier)+;
identifier: IDENTIFIER
```

lexer.g4

```
tokens{
    SLASH
}

SLASH : '/' ->type(SLASH);

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]* -> pushMode(VALUE_MODE);

mode VALUE_MODE;

fragment ESC :  '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE) ;
fragment UNICODE : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX ;
fragment HEX : [0-9a-fA-F] ;

END_SLASH : '/' ->type(SLASH), popMode;
STRING: ((~( '\r' | '\n' | '\t' | ' ' | ';' | '{' | '"' | '\'' | ':' | '/' | '=' | '[' | ']' )~( '\r' | '\n' | '\t' | ' ' | ';' | '{' | ':' | '/' | '=' | '[' | ']')* )) ->popMode;// IDENTIFIER ;

mode BLOCK_COMMENT_MODE;
```

test rule:

```
/aaa/aaabbb
```

We would need lexer in VALUE_MODE to pop out when it finds '/' (END_SLASH) 
Why is STRING rule prioritized over END_SLASH? What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it works following way:

lexer:

```
RPC_KEYWORD : 'rpc'-> pushMode(VALUE_MODE);
```

parser:

```
rule1 : RPC_KEYWORD

rule2 : [a-z]+
```

example1: rpca

matches rule2 (longer one), rule order doesn't matter

example2: rpc

matches rule1, rule order matters

Answer (score 0):

At first read, it appears this is the sequence of operations. Your question is not clear about whether or not this is what you expected.

1. Rule `SLASH` matches token `/`
2. Rule `IDENTIFIER` matches token `aaa`

   - Push mode `VALUE_MODE`
3. Rule `END_SLASH` matches token `/`

   - Set type of token to `SLASH`
   - Pop mode
4. Rule `IDENTIFIER` matches token `aaabbb`

   - Push mode `VALUE_MODE`
5. End of file.

Comment: What you have written is what we really want, but in reality
it goes to STRING rule rather than END_SLASH.
So, our question remains same: Why is STRING rule prioritized over END_SLASH?